# Unable to implement a working setup for private images and documents in wagtail

Tags: wagtail, x-sendfile

in a wagtail project, I need all image and document file URLs to be "private", e.g. to respect the "[privacy setting](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/editor_manual/documents_images_snippets/collections.html#privacy-settings)" of the collection that file/instance belongs to.
Further, these URLs must be private even if the URL is known/guessable.

For wagtail documents, I've found:
https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/settings.html?highlight=sendfile#documents 
which works.

I've expected a similar setup/reference for wagtail images, but got:
https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/images/image_serve_view.html#advanced-configuration

I did not manage to successfully implement this image_serve_view-sendfile-configuration.

Anyone knows a way to serve wagtail images the same way as wagtail documents (via the simple setting [`WAGTAILDOCS_SERVE_METHOD`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/settings.html?highlight=WAGTAILDOCS_SERVE_METHOD#documents)?

I'm OK with the StreamingResponse in case `django-sendfile` is not installed. I just want my wagtail documents AND images to respect the privacy level defined via the collections privacy setting (e.g. "Private, only accessible for logged-in users").

But even with a more elegant and performant solution via [django-sendfile](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile) (or a more up-to-date and maintained fork like [django-sendfile2](https://github.com/moggers87/django-sendfile2)) I'm missing documentation which details the steps to implement this setup for wagtail documents **and** wagtail images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enforcing privacy for images is not as simple as documents for the reasons described in this issue:

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3880#issuecomment-332798643

That issue has been referenced more [recently](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/6655#issuecomment-749173855), so i believe is still the case. It is marked as 'someday' (valid but lower priority).

This is not a full answer, but hopefully helps articulate the problem.

Comment: Thanks - the issues mentioned by @autopietic  are a better description than the wording in my own question. Until the wagtail collection privacy settings for images and documents behave as the should be, I will implement this permission check via https://github.com/edoburu/django-private-storage (my use case is somewhat special, as I only need these settings for instances of media files added via a custom wagtail formbuilder).